# FileInputStream error in SonarQube

Tags: android, file-io

I am getting `SonarQube` critical issue at below code

The problem is, sonarqube suggesting me to use `try-with-resources` which is only for above `API LEVEL 19+` and i am targeting to `LEVEL 16` as `minimumSDK`.

either way it is showing that close `FileInputStream` in `finally` block which i have already done in below code.

```
  protected void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        if (source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }

    } finally {
        if (source != null && destination != null) {

            source.close();
            destination.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Even android studio gives red-line error and suggests the same to use `try-with-resources` OR close stream in `finally` block.

> UPDATE

[image: Pre check exception by SonarLint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're only closing the two channels if both are null, and you are not closing the streams. Try extracting the check/close to separate blocks like:

```
protected void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        source = fis.getChannel();
        fout = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        destination = fout.getChannel();
        if (source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }

    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to close source input stream.");
            }
        }
        if (source != null) {
            try {
                source.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to close source channel.");
            }
        }
        if (fout != null) {
            try {
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to close destination output stream.");
            }
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            try {
                destination.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to close destination channel.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, and still giving error that says close stream in finally block

Comment: Sorry, it's because close() may throw an Exception. I'll update the answer.

Comment: please check my updated question. i have used your updated solution.

Comment: Oh, you need to close the streams and not just the channels. I'll update.

Comment: This is the solution. If you wan to improve a bit this, you can extract a common method work with Closeable (InputStream objects and children implement it). It'd like something like that. 

    private static void closeSafely(Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable != null) {
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube is giving a critical issue because there is a scenario when one of `source` or `destination` streams is not `null`. Also, you are not closing the `FileInputStream` objects and only closing their channels. In that case you would not close that `FileChannel`. See this line:

```
if (source != null && destination != null) {...}
```

In order to avoid this, you can do the following:

1: Split close of FileChannel as @fejd suggested.

2: Nested `try-catch` blocks, with each `finally` block closing their own streams.

One a general note, you can use `2` in more complex scenarios, but for the given one, `1` should suffice.